# Which polynomials in the minors of a matrix are invariant under conjugation?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, representation-theory, determinant, invariant-theory

Let $1<k<n$ be a fixed integer. I am trying to understand "what can be said" about the $k$-degree minors of a linear map $T:V \to V$, when $\dim V=n$.

Unlike the determinant, the $k$-minors are *not* invariant under conjugation. So, we cannot associate an ordered sequence of minors to $T$, independently of the basis we choose for representing it. This raises the following question:

Consider the action of $\text{GL}(n)$ on $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$:

$$ (M , A) \to \bigwedge^k M \circ A \circ \bigwedge^k M^{-1}.$$

After choosing a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can identify $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n) $ with $\mathbb{R}^{\binom{n}{k}^2}$.

> Can we classify all the polynomials $P:\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ which are invariant under the "conjugation-action" by $\text{GL}(n)$ described above?

Of course, every polynomial on $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$ which is invariant under the conjugation action of $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$
would be invariant under conjugation by the smaller subgroup which "comes from the copy of $\text{GL}(n)$ below".

[These polynomials are classified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181237/the-stucture-of-invariant-polynomials-on-matrix).

*A starting point would be to know whether there are any other invariant polynomials, besides the $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^n)$-invariant.*

Comment: Cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311151/which-polynomials-in-the-minors-of-a-matrix-are-invariant-under-conjugation.  When you cross-post, you should make sure that each post contains a link to the other, to minimize the chances of someone spending a lot of time trying to solve your questions when it's already answered on the other site.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I shall try to remember that for next time.