# Expressions of higher Casimir operators

Tags: lie-algebras, symmetric-polynomials, semisimple-lie-algebras

The center of the universal enveloping algebra of a semisimple Lie algebra (say over $\mathbb{C}$) $\mathfrak{g}$ is known to be a finite rank polynomial algebra. The justification I know involves the Harish-Chandra isomorphism $S(\mathfrak{g})^\mathfrak{g}\simeq S(\mathfrak{h})^W$ where $\mathfrak h$ is a Cartan subalgebra and $W$ the Weyl group. The [Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley-Shephard-Todd_theorem) states exactly than $S(\mathfrak{h})^W$ is a polynomial algebra. We also have the degree of the homogeneous generators of the invariant algebra [1].

A set of free generators of $Z(\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}))\simeq S(\mathfrak{g})^\mathfrak{g}$ is of course non-unique, but the two usual presentations I see are given by traces of powers or by elementary symmetric polynomials, both in the adjoint representation (see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182871/generators-of-invariant-polynomials-of-semisimple-lie-algebra)). These being polynomials on $\mathfrak{g}$, we obtain elements of $S(\mathfrak{g})$ via the ($ad$-equivariant) Killing form.

They both generate the same algebra, that is the polynomials on $\mathfrak{g}$ that are invariant under any linear automorphisms (or infinitesimal automorphisms), this is for example proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/find-conjugation-invariant-functions-without-using-eigenvalues). The corresponding polynomials are then necessarily invariant under the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{g}$.

**My question**: Can we directly justify that they generate the whole $S(\mathfrak{g}^*)^{\mathfrak g}$ algebra? I have seen in several places (like [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9609060) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element#General_case)) that it is a consequence of the Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem but I don't see how.

[1] : [Chevalley, Invariants of Finite Groups Generated by Reflections](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372597)